Self-terminating a c++ linux process when it is in a hung/frozen state
We have a process written in C++ running on linux server which reads a query from an input file, runs some calculations/algorithm on it and writes the results back on the command line. It's a multi-threaded so it can receive multiple queries at once and for each query, it spawns a new thread and writes results within the same thread. Owing to the requirement of high availability, scripts do auto-restart the process in case unforeseen crashes happen.
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 

void* func1(void* arg) 
{ 
    Validate();
    Calculate();
    WriteResults();
} 

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    //set signal handlers to handle SIGTERM, SIGKILL etc
    int rc;
    pthread_t ptid;
    //read config
    //...
    //...
    //listen for queries in a while loop
    while(1)
    {
        //read a query from an input file
        //validate it
        rc = pthread_create(&ptid,(pthread_attr_t*)NULL, &func1, (void*)Ptr);
        if(rc == 0)
            pthread_detach(ptid);
    }
}

A worst case scenario is when the process freezes or goes into a hung state without crashing and cannot take requests any longer. We have decided to make the process terminate itself whenever a scenario such as this happens.
From the high level up, we have decided to spawn a thread as soon as the the program starts which will keep checking a map for active queries and their last active times. If the inactivity exceeds a certain pre-configured time, then terminate the process.
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <map>

std::map<int id, QueryStruct> activeQueries;

void* func1(void* arg) 
{ 
    Validate();
    Calculate();
    WriteResults();
} 

void* func2(void* arg) 
{ 
    while (true)
    {
       //sleep for 300 seconds
       //check activeQueries in the system and their last activity time
       //if query inactive for more than pre-configured time, terminate the process.
    }
} 

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    //set signal handlers to handle SIGTERM, SIGKILL etc
    int rc;
    pthread_t ptid, ptid2;
    //read config
    //...
    //spawn a new thread which activates every 300 seconds (pre-configured time)
    pthread_create(&ptid2, NULL, &func2, NULL); 
    //listen for queries in a while loop
    while(1)
    {
        //read a query from an input file
        //validate it
        rc = pthread_create(&ptid,(pthread_attr_t*)NULL, &func1, (void*)Ptr);
        if(rc == 0)
            pthread_detach(ptid);
    }
}

Is there a more standard or better way to implement the same ?
What intricacies do I need to take care of while implementing the same ?

Unforeseen crashes should not happen. It point to bugs in your code. You are far better to find those bugs & fix them rather try some bandaid.

If your working threads are hanging (or crashing), using a supervising thread is not a good idea. The program probably has undefined behavior which will affect the supervisor too. A supervisor should be a separate process that is unaffected by whatever goes on in the worker process.

"A worst case scenario is when the process freezes or goes into a hung state"  Well-written programs do not do that.  You should attach gdb to a process doing that so you can see where your program is failing.

Sidenote: Why are you using pthreads in your C++ program? Is it a pre C++11 program?

A side note: pthread_detach - detaching a thread (insetad of joining it) is usually an indication of a design flaw.

@BobGoddard we do fix those bugs that cause crashes almost every time. This question specifically caters to the scenario where process goes into a hung state and doesn't crash

@TedLyngmo currently it is pre C++11 though we are working on getting it to C++11 at the very least.

It doesn't matter whether they crash or go into a hung state, both mean you have bugs in your program.


We have decided to make the process terminate itself whenever a scenario such as this happens.

The biggest problem I see with your plan is that many kinds of crash mess with the state of the C/C++ runtime.
This includes things like the ability to malloc or free, the state of the helper thread's memory, etc.
The standard way to isolate some code from another badly behaved code is to put it in a separate process.  This gives it its own memory space, etc.  You can communicate back and forth using various forms of inter process communication - named pipes, files on disk, sockets, etc.
If you do this, then failure of your program can be almost entirely isolated from your watchdog.
I might do it in 3 parts.

The first part is the worker.  It should regularly give "proof of progress" - proof it is doing work at an acceptable rate.  This proof should be reasonably strong - new tasks being completed for example (and not "we have an integer that code increments every time it does work" with no upper value) - in order to prevent an infinite loop from looking like infinite progress.

An in-process thread that monitors that "proof of progress" and relays it to the watchdog process.  Its only job is to find the proof of progress and send reports to the watchdog.


This task may also check that the watchdog exists; if it does not, it starts it.  (This is to defend slightly against watchdog crashes; but the big benefit is that users of the program don't have to start the watchdog themselves!).

A watchdog that listens for regular proofs of progress, and (to some extent) checks them.  Make sure the message isn't just "everything is ok", because the in-process thread is not to be trusted completely!  When it stops hearing reports of regular proofs of progress, it kills the main process and restarts it.

I'd have cleanup of the persistent state after a crash be part of the main program, to keep the watchdog simple.  It listens through some IPC, notices the progress proofs are missing, then restarts the worker process.  This cleanup should be done at startup, not at shutdown (as at shutdown you don't trust your program to be working properly; at startup, you should have more reason to have faith).
I did say 3 parts.  But I would recommend a 4th:

Finally, a 4th part; a crash log.  You should capture the state of the worker process when it fails.  Generate a crash log as best you can that allows a developer to debug the state the app was in when it failed.  This will allow you to have some chance of finding the bugs that are causing the problems.

You store a bounded number of logs (which should include binary dumps and maybe some information about what data triggered it).  Making this storage bounded is important (the number of systems that died from crash log filling up the disk is going to be large) as you should assume eventually your program will be neglected.  A bounded number of logs (the bound could even be 1, which is better than 0; but you could limit it to a larger number, or even an amount of resources) gives you some hope of actually improving the situation.
And one day some customer may want to pay you to fix a problem caused by these crashes and you'll thank yourself for these logs.

Stressing the need for reports of real and measurable proof of progress. I've seen too many systems provide trivial reports that are interpreted as acceptable functioning when the system's not actually doing anything useful, like being stuck in the reporting loop and continuously crapping out glowing reports of success.

@user4581301 I keep on imagine a "are you alive" and the worker (who is on step ~2^13 out of 2^31-1 of some nigh infinite subtask) saying "progress progress progress progress"
